# Remove empty TextCell[] from numerical expression

Tags: replacement, output

I am evaluating an expression like this:

```
(2 x[t] Derivative[1][x][t] + 
  2 y[t] Derivative[1][y][t] + 
  2 z[t] Derivative[1][z][t])/(
 2 Sqrt[x[t]^2 + y[t]^2 + 
   z[t]^2]) /. {x'[t] -> dz (x/d) , 
  y'[t] -> dz (y/d), z'[t] -> dz, x[t] -> x, 
  y[t] -> y, z[t] -> z}
```

... where, eg, x=1, y=1, z=1, d=1, and dz=1.

This should produce a number, and I've found that for simpler expressions of the same format it works fine. However, this expression produces the output:

```
Out[337]= (4 + 2 TextCell[""])/(2 Sqrt[3])
```

Because of the `TextCell[""]`, I can't use the result in other calculations. How can I remove it from the result or otherwise extract the numerical value? Traditional functions like N[] or ToExpression[] don't do anything, and it has a weird type:

```
In[338]:= Head@ %

Out[338]= Times
```

Comment: Please post the WL code, not LaTex. Most likely there is a `TextCell` embedded somewhere in the expression.

Comment: Thanks for adding the WL code. Cannot reproduce the result in `Out[337]`. How did you make the replacements for "where, eg, x=1, y=1, z=1, d=1, and dz=1."?

Comment: @Rohit Namjoshi In my full code, this is part of the body of a slightly more complicated function with the parameters x,y,z,d,dz. For the purposes of testing I used (expression)/.{x->1, y->1, dz-> 1, z-> 1, d->1}. Both give me Out[337].

Comment: `ClearAll[x, y, t, dz, z, d]`, then I assigned `expression = <cut-and-paste-from-question>`, then `expression /. {x -> 1, y -> 1, dz -> 1, z -> 1, d -> 1}` and the result is `Sqrt[3]`.